# Why is my html script element eating up my body?

Tags: html

I'm sort of confused here.

Here is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          #renderCanvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            touch-action: none;
          }
    </style>
    <title>Cubing</title>
    <script src="hand.js" />
    <script src="cannon.js" />
    <script src="oimo.js" />
    <script src="babylon.js" />
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="renderCanvas"/>
    <script src="main.js" />
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I'm using babylonjs, but I doubt that matters.

When I open the page in the browser and hit F12, I can see the displayed html.

Here is what I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          #renderCanvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            touch-action: none;
          }
    </style>
    <title>Cubing</title>
    <script src="hand.js">
            <script src="cannon.js" />
            <script src="oimo.js" />
            <script src="babylon.js" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="renderCanvas"/>
            <script src="main.js" />
        </body>         

     </html>
    </script>       
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I got the same results on IE and chrome.  Why is it changed so much?  Does it matter?

Comment: `canvas` is not a self-closing tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Required_<.2Fcanvas>_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script>` tags can't use shortcut close tags. The syntax has to be `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` == HTML5

Comment: *sigh* I hate missing tags.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing script tags.

Change it from:

```
<script src="hand.js" />
<script src="cannon.js" />
<script src="oimo.js" />
<script src="babylon.js" />
```

To:

```
<script src="hand.js" /></script>
<script src="cannon.js" /></script>
<script src="oimo.js" /></script>
<script src="babylon.js" /></script>
```